# mapkit autocomplete with combobox

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, combobox, autocomplete

Good morning,

I working with swift 4 for osx and I trying to realize a "address autocomplete combobox"

That means:
the user start typing the address and the combobox should show possible addresses:

I tried this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var cbSourceAddress: NSComboBox!
var searchCompleter = MKLocalSearchCompleter()
    var searchResults = [MKLocalSearchCompletion]()
    var cbData = [String]()


    func numberOfItems(in comboBox: NSComboBox) -> Int {
        return cbData.count
    }


    func comboBox(_ comboBox: NSComboBox, objectValueForItemAt index: Int) -> Any? {
        return cbData[index] as AnyObject
    }



    // 1
    func comboBox(_ comboBox: NSComboBox, completedString string: String) -> String? {

        searchCompleter.queryFragment = cbSourceAddress.stringValue

        for data in cbData {
            if string.characters.count < data.characters.count{
                let statePartialStr = data.lowercased()[data.lowercased().startIndex..<data.lowercased().index(data.lowercased().startIndex, offsetBy: string.characters.count)]
                if statePartialStr.range(of: string.lowercased()) != nil {
                    print(data)
                    return data
                }
            }
        }
        return ""
    }


    // 2
    func completerDidUpdateResults(_ completer: MKLocalSearchCompleter) {
        searchResults = completer.results


        for x in 0 ..< completer.results.count {
          print(searchResults[x])
          cbData.append("\(searchResults[x])")
        }
        cbSourceAddress.reloadData()
    }
```

My print result:

```
<MKLocalSearchCompletion 0x60000105f350> New England Aquarium (1 Central Wharf, Boston, MA 02110-3309, United States)
<MKLocalSearchCompletion 0x6000012412f0> New England Lobster Market & Eatery (824 Cowan Rd, Burlingame, CA  94010, United States)
<MKLocalSearchCompletion 0x600001240f00> England-Idlewild Park and Dog Park (5550 Idlewild Rd, Burlington, KY  41005, United States)
<MKLocalSearchCompletion 0x60000105ecc0> Best Western Plus New Englander (1 Rainin Rd, Woburn, MA  01801, United States)
<MKLocalSearchCompletion 0x6000008408a0> Melbourne Grammar School - Wadhurst Campus (355 St Kilda Road, St Kilda Road VIC 3004, Australia)
```

How can I formatted in a "human optimized string"?
And is my way the correct way to realize the autocomplete process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, I found the solution: `print(searchResults[x].title)`